# How to reduce the size of generated pdf file from image without losing quality using Android pdf document API?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-compression, image-conversion

I am making a image to pdf converter app and I am using android pdf document API to convert the image to pdf but I cant figure out how do I reduce the size of generated pdf.
I tried using bitmap.compress() method to compress the image but it did not worked for me whether I set it to 0 or 100,the size of generated pdf always remains same.
Can anyone help me figure out how do I reduce the generated pdf size without losing the quality of image?
.Note: I tried many answer that were available on stack overflow but they did not worked for me.
Even though some of them worked but they reduced the quality of image.
**Here is my code on how I am converting image to pdf:**

```
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
                Log.d("yhjt", "dsjahfo   " + bitmap);
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), i + 1).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream);
                bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);
                Log.d("yhjt", "dsjahfo   " + bitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                Log.d("yhjt", "dsjahfo   " + page);
                pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                bitmap.recycle();
                try {
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
              file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MY_PDF");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }
            String txt = editText.getText().toString();
            Log.d("edit", "how " + txt);
            file1 = new File(file, txt + ".pdf");
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
                fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();

            }
            pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: `PdfDocument` is designed for printing, not for creating PDF files. You may need to investigate third-party libraries for generating PDFs.

Comment: You havent read my question properly actually i have already converted the image into pdf using android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument but the problem is generated pdf size is very large even for a single image so i need to compress the pdf to smaller size.

Comment: "but the problem is generated pdf size is very large even for a single image" -- that is because `PdfDocument` is designed for printing, not for creating PDF files. File size is not a significant consideration for printing. "so i need to compress the pdf to smaller size" -- you may need to investigate third-party libraries for generating PDFs, as they are more likely to have options with file size in mind.

Comment: iText library is there but i want to upload my app to playstore so i dont know if i can use it in my app or not.

Comment: btw Thanks for the information.